# What does "V.P." stand for in "$V.P.\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{x-i\infty}^{x+i\infty}e^{st}\frac{f(s)}{s}\,ds$"?

Tags: notation, laplace-transform

currently I am studying the Laplace transform and its inverse. Lately I came across the possible abbreviation "V.P." for example in
$$ \int_0^tF(\tau)\,d\tau = V.P.\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{x-i\infty}^{x+i\infty}e^{st}\frac{f(s)}{s}\,ds. $$
However, I have no idea what this "V.P." should mean. And yes, I have tried to google it.

Best regards,
Lukas

Comment: Is the language of the surrounding text French?

Comment: I am quite sure that I have read it in an english text too, but the one I just have right in front of me is **german**.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value#Notation

Comment: Thank you very much! If I understand this correctly - he means the integral where the possible singularities/points where either $f$ is not defined or $s=0$ are excluded.
This makes alot of sense to me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$V.P.$ is a French abbreviation for *valeur principale* – the Cauchy principal value. Here it signifies that the integral after $V.P.$ should be computed as
$$\lim_{t\to\infty}\int_{x-it}^{x+it}e^{st}\frac{f(s)}s\,ds$$

Comment: and the Integral formally excludes the values where $\frac{f(s)}{s}$ is not defined (e.g. at $s=0$), right?

Comment: @Lukas The CPV can be extended to handle cases where the path of integration goes through finite singularities.